# Extending factories in AngularJS TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I want to extend a angular factory with typescript, so I can have a specific factory, but it gives me an error when I try to run it.

```
module App.Services {

export interface IShared {
    documents: Array<any>;
}

export class Shared implements IShared {

public static serviceId = "shared";

datacontext: App.Services.IDatacontext;
documents: Array<any>;

  constructor(datacontext: App.Services.IDatacontext) {
     this.datacontext = datacontext;

     this.datacontext.getDocuments().success((documents) => {
        this.documents = documents;
     });
  }
}

editorApp.factory(Shared.serviceId, ['datacontext',
    (datacontext) => new Shared(datacontext)
]);
}
```

I want to extend the Shared class to the following class

```
module App.Services {

export interface ITemplateShared extends IShared {

}

export class TemplateShared extends Shared implements ITemplateShared {

    public static serviceId = "templateShared";

    datacontext: App.Services.IDatacontext;

    constructor(datacontext) {
        super(datacontext);
        //this.datacontext = datacontext;
    }
}

editorApp.factory(TemplateShared.serviceId, ['datacontext', 'shared',
    (datacontext) => new TemplateShared(datacontext)
]);
}
```

When I start it gives me an Unhandled exception at line 6, column 5 in templateShared.js

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> class TemplateShared extends Shared

Most likey issue: make sure `Shared` is loaded by the browser *before* `TemplateShared`. The order of loading in JavaScript / TypeScript is important.

I recommend using *external modules* to avoid this mistake : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: Fixed my problem by having them in the same file, so i can make sure the one is loaded before the other. Thank!